# If I have N1 samples from PDF p1 and N2 samples from PDF p2, what PDF describes the combined distribution?

Tags: density-function

If I have (for example) normal distributions $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$, what PDF (if any) will describe 1000 samples from p1 and 500 samples from p2?

[image: some PDFs]

i.e. is there a PDF describing the green histogram $x_1+x_2$?

Comment: $x_1+x_2$ is not the ideal way of describing combination of two samples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign priors to distributions, i.e. a RV is $2/3$ likely to be drawn from $p_1$ and $1/3$ likely to be drawn from $p_2$, then the new PDF will look like
$$p(x)=\frac{2}{3}p_1(x)+\frac{1}{3}p_2(x)$$
And, its histogram will be very much alike the green curve above.

Comment: @JarleTufto what I describe is a mixture distribution.